# Spring Batch exceptions logging

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a multi threaded step Spring batch job, which reads from database using JdbcPagingItemReader, processes and published messages to a jms queue.
I am trying to log every exception encountered at any stage irrespective of skip or not.

I  have tried SkipListener which did not work. 
Since SkipListener respects transaction boundaries,it fails to reach my logger code if the skip-limit is exceeded within the chunk itself.
Using a  custom SkipPolicy, i am able to log the exception but without item context.

Is there a way to log all exceptions with context?